# Using the cc crate, how do I force the use of a specific compiler?

Tags: rust, clang

My rust crate relies on a single C source file (whose functions aren t used for export outside the crate) using clang specific s C language extensions.

What s the syntax for not using gcc or Microsoft cl, but always forcing the use of clang inside `build.rs`?

Comment: I don t need to use the `cc` crate as I remember a crate for building c source files using a library.

Comment: It looks like there is a function [`cc::Build::compiler`](https://docs.rs/cc/1.0.66/cc/struct.Build.html#method.compiler) to set the compiler executable, did you try that?

Comment: @rodrigo clang doesn t support fait lto objects which contains command line and can be linked without compiler support. How do I tell that the resulting file should be put inside the `rlib` like rust files since it also uses llvm and that the functions aren t exported?